# Org-mode: org-export-as-html is detected as XML, not HTML

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I am exporting my org-mode file via `org-export-as-html`, but when I check the file type via `file my/file.html`, it is XML. I notice the first three lines in my HTML exported file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

which is a reasonable explanation. If I manually re-order these lines to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

then the file is correctly identified as HTML. How do I correct this issue in my export function? I checked the org-mode docs here but they seem out of date:

http://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-Export-commands.html#HTML-Export-commands

because I do not have their listed commands, but `org-export-to-html` and `org-export-as-html-to-buffer`.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

BTW I am on Emacs 24.3 with Ubuntu 14.04. Here are the first few lines of my org file:

```
Flatsheet Project Mgmt -*- mode: org -*-
#+TODO: TODO IN-PROGRESS WAITING DONE
#+INFOJS_OPT: view:overview toc:true

* project stuff...
* more project stuff...
```

**UPDATE**

I found this link potentially helpful, but their suggestion is not working:

http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html

There is a section called `16.8.2 Export HTML without XML header`, but their solution below does not work for me:

```
(setq org-html-xml-declaration (quote (("html" . "")
                                       ("was-html" . "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"%s\"?>")
                                       ("php" . "<?php echo \"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"%s\\\" ?>\"; ?>"))))
```

Comment: when you do `org-version` what do you get, and did you try setting the equivalent of `org-html-doctype`?

Comment: XHTML *is* an XML document.  Why do care what `file` says?

Comment: @rekado Because my static "web server" (aka Amazon S3) was detecting the file at XML, thus it was not loading the javascript/css properly.

Comment: @pjammer you were right, I did not update my `org` package, which is apparently under heavy development. I was at 7.9x, but I upgrade to the latest stable and it works! It looks like they redid the exporter, which should make everything smoother from here on out :-)

Comment: In this case you may answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by upgrading to the latest version of org-mode, [detailed here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#updating-org)

I did it through the ELPA package manager, with marmalade packages, to upgrade org-mode from 7.9 to 8.2. Org-mode seems to be under heavy development, and it has a new export engine, which was probably the cause of my error.

When re-installing a package, just be sure to delete any existing org package directory under `.emacs/elpa/org...` and restart emacs with `emacs -q` and THEN install the latest package to avoid conflicts! YMMV but it worked for me.

After that, it exported fine, with a DOCTYPE html declaration at the top of the file. Now the file is recognized as HTML instead of XML.

Comment: Here's. [more information](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-8.0.html) on what's new on Org 8.0 and how it may affect your existing org-mode configuration in your init file.

Comment: An alternative solution would have been to use pandoc to convert from org-mode to html 5.

Answer (score 1):

XML export is still the default as of org 9.4, but you can override in several ways. For example, I export as html5 by putting this in my init file:

```lisp
(setq org-html-doctype "html5")
```

You can also set this per-file with this at the top:

```
#+HTML_DOCTYPE: html5
```

Using either of these methods generates this html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```